# In modern terms (for example the 2017 US dollar), how much purchasing power is 50,000 (French) Francs in 1829?

Tags: economy, france, money

Not simply a conversion of money, as even independent of inflation, the value of basics like bread and such change over time. I am reading "The Count of Monte Cristo" and a character has just remarked that 50,000 Francs is "a large sum, but not a fortune". Would this be, for example, enough to purchase a upper-middle class home in Paris at the time?

Comment: I seem to recall that this question has been asked before; the consensus answer is that there is no commonly accepted way to compare wealth across time.  There are a variety of methods, but all of them are flawed, and each of them will evoke argument from the proponents of the others.

Comment: I'd normally recommend MeasuringWorth.com as they have all of the various relative value measures, but they don't do it for the old Franc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This Wikipedia article (in French)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89volution_du_pouvoir_d%27achat_des_monnaies_fran%C3%A7aises#Quelques_salaires_annuels_.C3.A0_Paris_et_le_cours_de_m.C3.A9taux_pr.C3.A9cieux_en_1828) lists the annual salary in francs of several employees of [Jacques Augustin Catherine Pajou](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques-Augustin-Catherine_Pajou) in 1828, after his death, probably close enough to OP's time frame to be adequate:

> - sa cuisinière [his cook] 350 francs;
> - son domestique [his maid] 500 francs;
> - son jardinier [his gardener] 700 francs;

Also listed is an inventory and assessment of three valuable items from the estate:

> - deux médailles en argent pesant ensemble cinq kilogrammes huit cent soixante grammes sont prisées à raison de deux cents quatre francs cinquante centimes le kilogramme pour 1.201 f 30 [Two silver medals weighing five kilograms eight hundred and sixty grams are prized at the rate of two hundred and four francs fifty cents per kilogram for 1,201 f 30]
> - Une médaille en or pesant cent quarante un gramme quarante-neuf centième est prisée 439 f 50. [A gold medal weighing one hundred forty one gram forty-nine hundred is prized 439 f 50.]